# How to append content in javascript using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display content in a div whose id is search_result, I am using following code but it is only showing the last element of the array because of innerHTML. Can anyone help me to append the data.

here is my JavaScript code

```
function myFunction($qw) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < data.length; $i++) {
        $dis = data[$i].charAt(0);
        var $n = ($dis.localeCompare($qw))
        if ($n == 0)
            document.getElementById("search_result").innerHTML = (data[$i] + "<br/>");
    }
    $i = 0;
}
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="search_result">
</div>
```

Comment: Atleast use some logics and do some efforts before posting such questions

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=`. You are replacing what is already contained in the element by setting it to a new value every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing the content of the div with every step in your `for.. loop`.

```
function myFunction($qw)
        {
    //set  a var
    var new_content;
        for($i=0;$i<data.length;$i++){
        $dis = data[$i].charAt(0);
        var $n = ($dis.localeCompare($qw))
        if($n == 0)
    //remove replacing the innerHTML here
    //instead, add content to the variable
        new_content+=data[$i] + "<br/>";
        }

    //replace content of div after the loop
    document.getElementById("search_result").innerHTML=new_content;
        $i=0;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to touch DOM on every change. I'd better do this way:

```
function myFunction($qw) {
  var display = [];
  var $dis;
  var $n; 
  for (var $i = 0; $i < data.length; $i++) {
    $dis = data[$i].charAt(0);
    $n = ($dis.localeCompare($qw))
    if ($n == 0)
        display.push(data[$i]);
  }
  $i = 0;
  document.getElementById("search_result").innerHTML = display.join('<br />');
}
```

Or fancy way

```
function myFunction($qw) {
  var display = data.filter(function (el) {
    var $dis = el.charAt(0);
    var $n = $dis.localeCompare($qw);
    return $n === 0;
  });
  document.getElementById("search_result").innerHTML = display.join('<br />');
}
```

Also use `var` statement to initialize variables

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Sachin's answer, cache the string and then add it entirely to the dom afterwards:

```
function myFunction($qw) {
    var str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < data.length; $i++) {
        $dis = data[$i].charAt(0);
        var $n = ($dis.localeCompare($qw))
        if ($n == 0)
            str += (data[$i] + "<br/>");
    }
    document.getElementById("search_result").innerHTML = str;
    $i = 0; 
}
```